# Can shapefiles have image attachments?

Tags: shapefile, file-geodatabase, personal-geodatabase, attachments

I know feature classes inside a File geodatabase or personal geodatabase can have attachments enabled.

Can a shapefiles have image attachments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, shapefiles cannot have attachments. However, you could explore using the [hyperlinks](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-hyperlinks.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_5943D229F714460C8A4B2561A9F17275) functionality if the images are stored in a location with a URL.